# Zero-filled results for unused (but matching) rules

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a grammar similar to the following:

```
ruleFormat %= ruleComment | ruleSpec;
ruleFile %= ruleFormat % ruleNewline;
```

And rules are so declared:

```
rule<Iterator, void()> ruleComment;
rule<Iterator, int()> ruleSpec, ruleFormat;
rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>()> ruleFile;
```

(I am not actually using `int`, but a structure with some `int`s in it).

Well, the grammar seems to work properly: when `ruleSpec` matches an integer, the rule has that attribute which is in turn given to the vector.

The problem is when `ruleComment` matches in `ruleFormat`, because the data is set to be null, and a null value is placed inside the vector. The result is that the vector is filled with a mix of "right" values and "wrong" zeroes.

How can I prevent this from happening?

EDIT:
as requested, here a sample code:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct MyGrammar: public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<int>()> {
    MyGrammar(): MyGrammar::base_type(ruleFile) {
        ruleComment = qi::lit('@');
        ruleSpec %= qi::int_;

        ruleFormat %= ruleComment | ruleSpec;
        ruleFile %= ruleFormat % ' ';

        ruleComment.name("COMMENT");
        ruleSpec.name("SPEC");
        ruleFormat.name("FORMAT");
        ruleFile.name("FILE");

        qi::debug(ruleComment);
        qi::debug(ruleSpec);
        qi::debug(ruleFormat);
        qi::debug(ruleFile);
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, void()> ruleComment;
    qi::rule<Iterator, int()> ruleSpec, ruleFormat;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>()> ruleFile;
};

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator Iter;
    std::string subj = "0 @ @ 12 3 @ 4 @ 56 @ ";

    MyGrammar<Iter> gram;
    qi::parse(subj.cbegin(), subj.cend(), gram);
    return 0;
}
```

From the debug information, I am getting:

```
<attributes>[[0, 0, 0, 12, 3, 0, 4, 0, 56, 0]]</attributes>
```

while I'd like to obtain is avoid to place 0 in the vector when `@` matches

```
<attributes>[[0, 12, 3, 4, 56]]</attributes>
```

Comment: Code would help here.  Can you keep it minimal please?>

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit short of time, but I'll try to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Haha. We're also short on time. You didn't show  the declaration of `ruleFormat`. This is the most crucially interesting bit.

Comment: Oops sorry, I'll fix it immediately!

Comment: This describes the same situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038186/boost-spirit-qi-omit-element-in-kleene-star-parser

Comment: @AkiRoss thanks for updating with a SSCCE (module `#include` line). I agree with the MikeM, voting as a duplicate.