# Spirit Qi: Completely ignoring output of some rules

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm parsing some input that is vaguely structured like C-ish code.  Like this:

```
Name0
{
 Name1
 {
  //A COMMENT!!

  Param0 *= 2
  Param2 = "lol"
 }
}
```

Part of that is comments, which I want to totally ignore (and it's not working).  I consider two things to be a `node`, the named scopes (`category` rule) like `Name0 {}` and the values (`param` rule) like `Param0 *= 2`... then there is `comment`.  I've tried setting things up like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<Category>, Param> Node;

qi::rule<Iterator, Node(), ascii::space_type> node;
```

So the `node` rule puts either a `Category` or a `Param` in a `variant`.  Here are the other rules (I've omitted some rules that don't really matter for this):

```
qi::rule<Iterator> comment; //comment has no return type

qi::rule<Iterator, Category(), ascii::space_type> category;
qi::rule<Iterator, Param(), ascii::space_type> param;
```

And their actual code:

```
comment = "//" >> *(char_ - eol);

param %=
 tagstring
 >> operators
 >> value;

category %=
 tagstring
 >> '{'
 >> *node
 > '}';

node %= comment | category | param;
```

`comment` is setup to use `=` instead of `%=`, and it has no return type.  However, comments end up creating null `Category`s in my output `Node`s wherever they show up.  I've tried moving `comment` out of the `node` rule and into `category` like this:

```
category %=
 tagstring
 >> '{'
 >> *(comment | node)
 > '}';
```

And various other things, but those null entries keep popping up.  I had to make `comment` output a string and put `std::string` in my `Node` `variant` just to sorta catch them, but that messes up my ability to stick in commenting in other parts of my rules (unless I actually grab the string in every location).

How can I completely ignore the `comment` and have it not show up in any output in any way?

edit: You'd think `omit` would do it, but didn't seem to change anything...

edit 2: Referencing [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20144036/173342), I have a shaky solution in this:

```
node %= category | param;

category %=
 tagstring
 >> '{'
 >> *comment >> *(node >> *comment)
 > '}';
```

However, I want to try to stick comments into all sorts of places (between `tagstring` and `{`, in my unshown `root` rule between root `category`s, etc).  Is there a simpler method than this?  I was hoping it could be done with a simple `>> commentwrapper` plugged into wherever I wanted...

Comment: Skippers are the way to go. Please have a look at this question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672316/boost-spirit-skipper-compile-time-error

Comment: @MikeM Thanks for that link!  Fixed my problem, and outlined exactly how in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so making your own skipper isn't too bad.  And it elegantly solves this commenting problem, just as Mike M said.  I define my rules in a struct called `Parser` that is templated with an `Iterator`.  Had to make some adjustments to use the skipper.  First, here is the skipper which is defined in `Parser` with all my other rules:

```
typedef qi::rule<Iterator> Skipper;
Skipper skipper;
```

So `skipper` is a rule of type `Skipper`.  Here is what my `Parser` struct looked like originally, where it was using the `ascii::space` rule of type `ascii::space_type` as its skipper, which IS NOT the same type as `qi::rule<Iterator>` that `skipper` is based on!

```
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Category>(), ascii::space_type>
{
 qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Category>(), ascii::space_type> root;

 ...
```

So every instance of `ascii::space_type` in the rule templates must be replaced with `Skipper`!  That includes other rules besides the `root` that is shown here, such as `param` and `category` from my question.  Leaving any remnant of the old `ascii::space_type` behind gives cryptic compiler errors.

```
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Category>(), qi::rule<Iterator>>
{
 typedef qi::rule<Iterator> Skipper;
 Skipper skipper;

 qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Category>(), Skipper> root;

 ...
```

The original skipper was merely `space`, mine is now an alternative of `space` and `comment`.  No old functionality (space skipping) is lost.

```
skipper = space | comment;
```

Then the `phrase_parse` call needs to be adjusted from this old version that used `ascii::space`:

```
bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, ascii::space, result);
```

to

```
bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, parser.skipper, result);
```

And now comments disappear as easily as white space.  Awesome.

Comment: Looks good. You could additionally use a template argument for the skipper, so it would be a bit more flexible in the future. ``template<Iterator, Skipper> struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, data_type, Skipper>``

Comment: @MikeM I actually chose to define the skipper within the struct to consolidate my rule definitions, rather than define the skipper alone in a different function.  Maybe it's not the best choice, but it seems the most convenient for me in this circumstance.